# Get the list of tables used in a stored-procedure for a database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

our company is planning to administer the report server database and the requirement is to get the list of the tables used in stored-procedures in the productions server database.Is there any query/function to retrieve this information ?

Comment: If your procedures use dynamic code like select @Tname = 'MyTable' + datename(year, getdate()); exec('select * from ' + @Tname) it's not possible to determine if MyTable2018 is used or not

Comment: But you can try to use sys.sql_expression_dependencies and sys.sql_modules.definition like ...

Answer (score 4):

If you use dynamic SQL to construct table names (or accept them as arguments), or use nested views, it becomes very difficult to automate this. However if you stick to traditional T-SQL and proper references you can get there with this:

```
DECLARE @procid int = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.procedurename');

;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT name = 
      COALESCE(QUOTENAME(d.referenced_server_name)   + N'.', N'')
    + COALESCE(QUOTENAME(d.referenced_database_name) + N'.', N'')
    + QUOTENAME(d.referenced_schema_name) + N'.'
    + QUOTENAME(d.referenced_entity_name)
  FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
  WHERE d.referencing_id = @procid
)
SELECT name FROM src GROUP BY name;
```

And if you just want a catalog of all references, you can do this:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT [procedure] = QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(o.name),
      ref = 
      COALESCE(QUOTENAME(d.referenced_server_name)   + N'.', N'')
    + COALESCE(QUOTENAME(d.referenced_database_name) + N'.', N'')
    + QUOTENAME(d.referenced_schema_name) + N'.'
    + QUOTENAME(d.referenced_entity_name)
  FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
  ON d.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE o.[type] = N'P'
)
SELECT [procedure],ref 
  FROM src
  GROUP BY [procedure],ref;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
; WITH MYTABLES_CTE  (SchemaName, ProcedureName, ServerName, DatabaseName, SchemaName2, TableName, ROW_CNT, TXT)
AS
 (
  SELECT  V.SchemaName 
        , V.ProcedureName
        , V.ServerName
        , V.DatabaseName
        , V.SchemaName2
        , V.TableName
        , V.ROW_CNT
        , CAST(V.SchemaName2 + '.' + V.TableName AS VARCHAR(MAX))

    FROM #VT_TEMP V
    WHERE ROW_CNT = 1

    UNION ALL

      SELECT  V.SchemaName 
        , V.ProcedureName
        , V.ServerName
        , V.DatabaseName
        , V.SchemaName2
        , V.TableName
        , V.ROW_CNT
        , CAST(TXT  + ', ' + V.SchemaName2 + '.' + V.TableName AS VARCHAR(MAX))

   FROM #VT_TEMP V INNER JOIN MYTABLES_CTE C
   ON V.SchemaName = C.SchemaName
   AND V.ProcedureName = C.ProcedureName
   AND V.ROW_CNT = C.ROW_CNT+1
)


SELECT DISTINCT VV.SchemaName 
        , VV.ProcedureName
        , VV.ServerName
        , VV.DatabaseName
        , VV.SchemaName2
        , VV.TableName
        , VV.ROW_CNT
        , VV.TXT
 FROM MYTABLES_CTE VV INNER JOIN ( SELECT ProcedureName
                                      , MAX(ROW_CNT) AS MX_CNT
                                 FROM MYTABLES_CTE C
                                 GROUP BY ProcedureName
                               ) SC
 ON VV.ProcedureName = SC.ProcedureName
 AND VV.ROW_CNT = SC.MX_CNT
```